# How are the stats of your ancients determined when using Call of the Ancients?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

I've noticed that your ancients are weaker than you, but what are their stats? And do they change depending on you're stats or your level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [description of the skill](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/barbarian/active/call-of-the-ancients).

> Each deals 60% weapon damage per swing in addition to bonus abilities.

I believe the bonus abilities work the same way yours do.

- [Talic uses the Whirlwind ability](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/barbarian/active/whirlwind), which does 110% of his damage.
- [Korlic uses the Cleave skill](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/barbarian/active/cleave), which does 120% of his damage.
- [Madawc uses the Weapon Throw skill](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/barbarian/active/weapon-throw), which does 100% of his damage and slows the enemy by 60%.

This can be altered using runes, however.

- The "Council Rises" rune increases damage to 66%.
- "Korlic's Might" increases Korlic's damage to 200% of **your** damage, by using the "[Furious Charge](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/barbarian/active/furious-charge)" skill.
- "Madawc's Madness" increases Madawc's damage to 180% of **your** damage by using the "[Seismic Slam](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/barbarian/active/seismic-slam)" skill.
- "Talic's Anger" increases Talic's damage to 250% of **your** damage by using the "[Leap](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/barbarian/active/leap)" skill.

Keep in mind that while the skills runes give you are similar in *behavior* to your skills, they do different amounts of damage.

Only thing I'm unsure of is how much health/armor/resistances/MF/etc each ancient has. An ancient *can* die, but I haven't been able to find any information on how much health they have. I assume their health/armor/resistance stats match yours unless anyone can prove otherwise or Blizzard comes out and explicitly says.